# nic configuration on a linux virtual machine (rackspace)

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, nic, ethtool

I am trying to check my nic speed and duplex setting on a vm I have at rackspace. It is centos 6.4.

When I run:

```
# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Link detected: yes
```

This is all I get back.

When I run mii-tool, I get an error:

```
mii-tool eth0
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth0' failed: Operation not supported
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is completely expected when you're running those commands from within a VM.

Rather than completely emulating a physical NIC your hypervisor is offering a paravirtualised network adapter which, with a compatible driver for the VM, offers much more performance with lower overhead.

You don't have a real network card and therefore you can't manipulate it as if it were. There simply is no link speed and there are no duplex settings for the VM, all of that if off-loaded to the hypervisor.

I'm not certain if Rackspace is using KVM [`virtio`](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Virtio)  technology or using [Xen](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Networking#Paravirtualised_Network_Devices) but the concept is the same.

Comment: Rackspace Cloud is running Xen

Comment: Ok, thanks, so how do you figure out the speed & duplex you are getting?

Comment: From the product specs and measuring/benchmarking e.g. with https://iperf.fr/ -